Deleting a GeoServer COG-based raster store and creating a new one, with same name and a different GeoTIFF, causes GeoServer error
I need to update the COG GeoTIFF at the basis of a GeoServer raster store.
Whether I just update the GeoTIFF file, or I remove the store (and related layer) and re-create a new one (with the same name), GeoServer returns this error when calling WCS/WMS:
java.lang.NullPointerException

If I use a new GeoServer instance (e.g., a new container), and create a store using the new GeoTIFF, it works perfectly.
So, it seems there is something cached in GeoServer even after removing store, layer, workspace, etc.
Any idea of what causes such a behavior?
GeoServer version is 2.24.1.
This is a screenshot of the store from GeoServer GUI:

This is a more exhaustive thread of the logs from GeoServer:
21 Jun 10:33:47 DEBUG  [io.imageio] - Unable to create a reader for overview: https://mys3/20240617.tif.ovr
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to read header for https://mys3/20240617.tif.ovr
    at it.geosolutions.imageioimpl.plugins.cog.HttpRangeReader.readHeader(HttpRangeReader.java:96)
    at it.geosolutions.imageioimpl.plugins.cog.DefaultCogImageInputStream.initializeHeader(DefaultCogImageInputStream.java:124)
    at it.geosolutions.imageioimpl.plugins.cog.DefaultCogImageInputStream.init(DefaultCogImageInputStream.java:84)
    at it.geosolutions.imageioimpl.plugins.cog.CogSourceSPIProvider.getStream(CogSourceSPIProvider.java:96)
    at org.geotools.coverage.grid.io.imageio.MaskOverviewProvider.externalOverviewsCheck(MaskOverviewProvider.java:267)
    at org.geotools.coverage.grid.io.imageio.MaskOverviewProvider.<init>(MaskOverviewProvider.java:172)
    at org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffReader.getHRInfo(GeoTiffReader.java:446)
    at org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffReader.<init>(GeoTiffReader.java:274)
    at org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffFormat.getReader(GeoTiffFormat.java:335)
    at org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffFormat.getReader(GeoTiffFormat.java:77)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getGridCoverageReader(ResourcePool.java:1669)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getGridCoverageReader(ResourcePool.java:1585)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CoverageInfoImpl.getGridCoverageReader(CoverageInfoImpl.java:174)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor216.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.ModificationProxy.invoke(ModificationProxy.java:144)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy138.getGridCoverageReader(Unknown Source)
    at org.geoserver.wcs.DefaultWebCoverageService100.getCoverage(DefaultWebCoverageService100.java:213)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor278.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.geoserver.ows.util.RequestObjectLogger.invoke(RequestObjectLogger.java:51)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:220)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy79.getCoverage(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor277.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.execute(Dispatcher.java:867)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:268)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1072)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:965)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:502)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:596)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleNonCORS(CorsFilter.java:328)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.flow.controller.IpBlacklistFilter.doFilter(IpBlacklistFilter.java:89)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.monitor.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:159)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.ows.HTTPHeadersCollector.doFilter(HTTPHeadersCollector.java:48)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.HTTPMethodFilter.doFilter(HTTPMethodFilter.java:36)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:194)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:39)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:337)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:196)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilterInternal(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:72)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:492)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:673)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:389)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1791)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to read header for https://mys3/20240617.tif.ovr. Code: 404. Reason: Not Found
    at it.geosolutions.imageioimpl.plugins.cog.HttpRangeReader.readHeader(HttpRangeReader.java:87)
    ... 142 more
21 Jun 10:33:47 DEBUG  [imageio.geotiff] - Logging ModelTransformation:
AffineTransform[[0.010000228881836, 0.0, 6.639999866485596], [0.0, 0.009998321533203, 36.650001525878906]]

21 Jun 10:33:47 DEBUG  [data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
21 Jun 10:33:47 DEBUG  [data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation  only.
21 Jun 10:33:47 DEBUG  [grid.io] - coverageName:20240617,imageChoice:0,subSamplingFactorX:118,subSamplingFactorY:104
21 Jun 10:33:47 DEBUG  [grid.io] - Coverage read: width = 11 height = 11
21 Jun 10:33:47 DEBUG  [coverage.processing] - Grid geometry has been adjusted for coverage "20240617".
21 Jun 10:33:47 DEBUG  [coverage.processing] - Resampled coverage "20240617" from coordinate system "WGS 84" (for an image of size 11×11) to coordinate system "WGS 84" (image size 10×10). JAI operation is "Warp" with "Nearest" interpolation on geophysics pixels values. Background value is (NaN).
21 Jun 10:33:47 INFO   [geoserver.wcs] - 
Request: getCoverage
    sourceCoverage = vento:20240617
    domainSubset:
        spatialSubset:
            envelope[0] = GeneralBounds[(6.639999866485596, 36.650001525878906), (18.52027177810669, 47.09824752807617)]
            gridGroup[0] = wcs:grid=net.opengis.gml.impl.RectifiedGridTypeImpl@3b06a399 (srsName: null) (limits: GridEnvelope2D[0..9, 0..9], axisName: [x, y], dimension: 2)
            grid[0]:
                limits = GridEnvelope2D[0..9, 0..9]
                axisName[0] = xaxisName[0] = y
                dimension = 2
    rangeSubset:
    interpolationMethod = nearest neighbor
    output:
        crs:
            value = EPSG:4326
        format:
            value = GeoTIFF
    service = WCS
    version = 1.0.0
    baseUrl = http://localhost:8600/geoserver/
21 Jun 10:33:47 DEBUG  [grid.io] - Disposing writer:org.geoserver.ows.DispatcherOutputStream@2f29e47f
21 Jun 10:33:47 INFO   [geoserver.servlets] - OutputStream was successfully aborted.
21 Jun 10:33:47 ERROR  [geoserver.ows] - 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.media.jai.PlanarImage.getData(PlanarImage.java:2110)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.getData(RenderedOp.java:2276)
    at it.geosolutions.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageWriter.writeTile(TIFFImageWriter.java:1831)
    at it.geosolutions.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageWriter.write(TIFFImageWriter.java:2927)
    at it.geosolutions.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageWriter.write(TIFFImageWriter.java:2621)
    at org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffWriter.writeImage(GeoTiffWriter.java:392)
    at org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffWriter.write(GeoTiffWriter.java:246)
    at org.geoserver.wcs.responses.GeoTiffWriterHelper.write(GeoTiffWriterHelper.java:182)
    at org.geoserver.wcs.responses.GeoTIFFCoverageResponseDelegate.encode(GeoTIFFCoverageResponseDelegate.java:118)
    at org.geoserver.wcs.response.Wcs10GetCoverageResponse.write(Wcs10GetCoverageResponse.java:118)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.response(Dispatcher.java:1018)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:272)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1072)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:965)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:502)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:596)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleNonCORS(CorsFilter.java:328)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.flow.controller.IpBlacklistFilter.doFilter(IpBlacklistFilter.java:89)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.monitor.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:159)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.ows.HTTPHeadersCollector.doFilter(HTTPHeadersCollector.java:48)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.HTTPMethodFilter.doFilter(HTTPMethodFilter.java:36)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:194)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:39)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:337)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:196)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilterInternal(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:72)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:492)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:673)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:389)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1791)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)



It's looking for an overview and can't find it

@IanTurton it seems that both versions of geotiff do not contain overviews. Any idea why one of them (that used to create first time the store) does not produce the error, while the other does?

can it be a COG without overviews? no idea, why it works once and not the 2nd time - attach a debugger and step through

A GTiff without overviews is, by definition, NOT a COG.

Overviews in COG are optional https://github.com/cogeotiff/cog-spec/blob/master/spec.md. If the use case requires data in native resolution then overviews are not needed, but applications can still get subsets of data effectively with HTTP range requests.
